# How to debug with url parameters

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I can see you can get url parameters by using Param("MyParam"). But how do you debug this? When you click the play button this does have a url parameter so how you develop you app where having url parameters is part of the application flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to view/interact with a PowerApp:

1. The "Studio" (aka: The Editor) where you build the PowerApp
2. The "Web Player" (browser-based app interface)
3. The "Mobile Player" (PowerApps container app-based interface)

To work with/debug the `Param()` function, you can create a label in the app set to the param value, then open the app in either 2 or 3 above to view its value.